# NetBeans 8.0.2 and scene builder 2.0 datepicker class not supporting

Tags: java, netbeans, datepicker, fxml, scenebuilder

I am using netBeans 8.0.2 to do an FXML project where I use Scene Builder 2.0 to format the GUIs. There is a datetime picker controller in scene builder 2.0 but when I add it save the scnene builder and run the FXML in netbeans, it shows an error in the FXML as datepicker class not available. What could be the solution for this?

```
<DatePicker layoutX="1564.0" layoutY="114.0" />
```

I dont know whether this supports nut this is the FXML code generated for datePicker class by scene builder.